# Licences for libraries when publishing application to Google Play store

Tags: android, google-play, publish, publishing

I built my app using [FirebaseUI-Android](https://github.com/firebase/) (firebaseui:firebase-ui-database) and squareup.picasso from github and I don't know anything about Licenses in github
What if i publish my app in google play without anything of Licenses just I use the libraries and don't know how I dealing with Licenses.
my app is for my users maybe for 20000 users and its for me not for a company.
please anyone explain this issue 
what should I do now if my app ready to publish in google play...??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not matter how many and what libraries you use in your application. Using libraries is legal and should not cause any issue considering licences when publishing your application to Google Play Store.

---

Good luck :)

Comment: I just use firebase database,core,auth,messaging.
picasso,firebase-ui-database

Comment: firebase-ui talking about License as individual or corporate
https://developers.google.com/open-source/cla/individual
https://developers.google.com/open-source/cla/corporate

Comment: You do not need to sign any of these documents if you want to publish an app to Play Store. These documents that you provided are for Github contributors to the firebase-ui open-source library and not for people that use it.

Comment: Thank you @TomasJablonskis you're amazing person